# How to change field information in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

I am making a database management system for a virtual transportation company in Visual Basic.

I have 3 tables in mysql: `operations, employees, vehicles`.

Each one of them has a flag like field with the status `(Active/Inactive)`. When i assign an employee and a vehicle to a new transporting operation the status field changed to `active` or `busy`.

When the driver returns and I click on `Conclude` to finish the operation, i want to change the status field in all the 3 tables like `Non-busy or concluded`.

I don't know how to do that, I don't know how to change the information of the 3 fields in 3 different tables with the just one click.

Comment: 3 tables have any same foreign key or primary key

Comment: All the 3 tables have primary and foreign keys, it's the employee code, operation code and vehicle code, those are unic. But what i really don't know is what code should i write in VB to make this work. With one table is fine, the app allready changes the operations status to "concluded". The hard part is making that automatically happen at the same time, change the status of the field identified with that code.

Comment: do you knw about trigger?. Use the trigger when one table has updated the update the other two tables

Comment: My teacher never taught us how to use triggers but let me see if i got the idea. When the operation status would change to "Terminated" a trigger that changes the other two status would be activated. Are triggers very hard to do?

Comment: No... Read this [1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx[1]. Then you understand the trigger.

Comment: Otherwise you update the 3 tables afer click Conclude use those primarykey field in where clause

Comment: How exactly are you communicating with the database? This is a fairly easy operation if you doing it with code. But if you are relying on VB to do it for you, it is not so easy. I'll submit my answer for you to look at below.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest (if you can change structure of tables) leave status field in the operation table only and check statuses of employees and vehicles  by checking an active operation for them. This way keep  data consistency in your system.

Comment: I like this approach: just wondering how would you cope with other reasons for inactive employees (e.g. holiday/sickness) or vehicles (e.g. maintenance)? @A.Barbosa, do you care about such complexities?

Answer (score 0):

First set up a listener for the button

```
AddHandler button.Click, addressof update_tables
```

Then set up the subroutine:

```
Private Sub update_tables()

   ' connect to the MySQL database
   Dim MyConn As New MySqlConnection("Server=ServerName; Database=db_name; user=username; password=password;")

   ' the following code will update the tables for you
    Dim MyCommand As New MySqlCommand()
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
    MyCommand.Connection = MyConn
    Dim query As String
    query = "update operations set flag = 'active' where driver = 'tom'; update employees set flag = 'active' where driver = 'tom'; update vehicles set flag = 'active' where driver = 'tom'"
    MyCommand.CommandText = query
    MyConn.Open()
    myReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader()
    myReader.Close()
    MyConn.Close()
    MyConn.Dispose()

End Sub
```

All three tables will be updated at once.

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts: why use `ExecuteReader` rather than `ExecuteNonQuery`? And I think you should wrap these in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-transaction) to ensure consistency (which would entail calling 3 statements in the transaction rather than your all-in-one query).